# How to get Event Listeners on HTML objects to get along with React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to wrap the VexFlow library in a react component to make an app to draw music sheets.

In VexFlow, there are notehead objects, so my idea was to draw all the noteheads and add event listeners to them that would then use submit to call some graphql function to update the music sheet.

So, to be clear, in my component that wraps the VexFlow library, in my componentDidMount(), after making all my notes, I'm getting the notes:

```
const notes = div.getElementsByClassName("vf-notehead");
```

Iterating on them:

```
for(let i = 0; i < notes.length; i++){
let note = notes[i];
```

And adding an event listener that attempts to submit call the submit prop:

```
            note.addEventListener("mouseUp", function() {
                this.index = i; // Hope this works, sometimes closures are weird
                if(this.props.sheet.keyIndexes.includes(this.index)){
                    this.props.sheet.keyIndexes.splice(this.state.keyIndexes.indexOf(this.index), 1);
                }else{
                    this.props.sheet.keyIndexes.push(this.index);
                }

                this.props.submit(this.props.sheet.id, this.props.sheet.keyIndexes); // updateProps and redraw canvas
            });
```

But this is silently failing. And frankly, it seems sort of hacky. Is there a better way to do this? I know this is working for other event handlers on the same notes. I'm pretty sure the point of failure is trying to connect back to react.

Comment: `this` inside the event handler callback isn't what you think it is. Use react `onMouseUp` instead of searching the dom for elements and using `addEventListener`

Comment: But how will onMouseUp know what note I'm clicking on? As far as I can tell, there's really no other way to access the noteheads for this sort of thing. Are you suggesting I try to wrap the noteheads in individual components? How would I do something like that?

Comment: Pass the note as a `prop` to whatever component you render that user would click on

Comment: Could you give a small example?

Comment: One way : `{notes.map((note,index)=> <NoteComponent onMouseup={() => this.playNote(note, index)}>{note}</NoteComponent>)}`

Comment: Oops... I misspelled `onMouseUp` in previous example

Comment: I don't have access to the notes directly. I pass in a set of a keys when I make a stave, like so:
`
new VF.StaveNote({
                    clef: "treble",
                    duration: "w", 
                    keys: ["e/4", "g/4", "b/4", "d/5", "f/5"] // every good boy does fine
                })`

And then I push them to an array and put them on and a voice, and then render them on a voice. Are you suggesting that I make the noteComponents from the dom elements that VexFlow makes? Can I even do that?

Comment: What generates the elements? The library or react?

Comment: VexFlow, the library I'm trying to wrap.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
notes[i].addEventListener("mouseUp", function() {
            this.index = i; // Hope this works, sometimes closures are weird
            if(this.props.sheet.keyIndexes.includes(this.index)){
                this.props.sheet.keyIndexes.splice(this.state.keyIndexes.indexOf(this.index), 1);
            }else{
                this.props.sheet.keyIndexes.push(this.index);
            }

            this.props.submit(this.props.sheet.id, this.props.sheet.keyIndexes); // updateProps and redraw canvas
        });
```